# CSS radial gradient for Safari not working

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser, css-gradients

When I use this snippet on Chrome, IE, and Firefox and it works fine! But on Safari it doesn't work.

This issue happens:

[image]

```css
.circle-red {
 border: 2px solid;
 border-radius: 51%;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 80px 40px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 10%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 32%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70% ), linear-gradient(160deg, transparent 10%, red 30%);
 background-size: 87.5% 55%, 100% 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-red"></div>
```

Comment: Which version of Safari are you using? It probably still requires a `-webkit-` prefix

Comment: @TylerH I'm using version 5.1.7

Comment: @TylerH how do I use this prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This adding a webkit prefix on your background-size property and on your background gradient value. Here is an example:

```
.circle-red {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 51%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 80px 40px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 10%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 32%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70% ), linear-gradient(160deg, transparent 10%, red 30%);
   background: -webkit-radial-gradient(ellipse at 80px 40px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 10%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 32%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70% ), linear-gradient(160deg, transparent 10%, red 30%);
    background-size: 87.5% 55%, 100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size: 87.5% 55%, 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks just woks without `ellipse` property.